# Why do Wordpress rewriites seem to work differently for posts vs pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

Because you can't duplicate a slug  in WordPress, we are getting round it by giving unique slugs to some sections of our website but rewriting the urls to get the desired structure:

```
add_rewrite_rule('product1/faqs/?', 'index.php?name=product1-faqs', 'top'); 
add_rewrite_rule('product2/faqs/?', 'index.php?name=product2-faqs', 'top');
```

This enables us to have an "faqs" directory within each product but of course the actual slug of that page is much different.

I've noticed that if you hit "product1/faqs/" in the browser, it successfully displays the  content  of "product1-faqs" but keeps the url as product1/faqs/ (which is desired) but only if it is POST.

If I try this same technique but on a PAGE, the browser URL flicks to "product1-faqs" (undesired!)

Why is that? I don't want have to limit ourselves just to posts for the sake of rewrites working as desired...

Comment: Why would you need to duplicate a slug?

Comment: It's a common issue for some people: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95758/allow-duplicate-permalink-slugs-for-posts-in-different-categories

Comment: I suggest you delete this question, & post it in the wordpress section on stackexchange.

Comment: For reference, I asked and got the right answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140783/why-do-wordpress-rewriites-seem-to-work-differently-for-posts-vs-pages